# use spark Scala dataframe cube/pivot to do Olap, always report attribute conflicts sql parsing error

Tags: parsing, apache-spark, dataframe, pivot, cube

Error reported always until I added a manual check point to save the data frame after cube and before pivot.

Only manual save and reload the table works, other ways such as persist or check point all no use.

My question is how to avoid this. The error message:

```
 Conflicting attributes: groupby_keys#90179
    ;;
    'Join UsingJoin(Inner,List(groupby_keys))
```

My code is a little mess for to test in spark-shell but anyways:

```
case class FlagsStr(groupby_keys: String, profit_flag_str: String, cmd_str: String, open_followed_str: String, close_followed_str: String, close_or_open_flag_str: String, point: Int)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

def merge_flags(flag1: String, flag2: String): String = {
  var ret: String = null
  if( flag1 != null & flag2 != null)
    ret = flag1 + "_" + flag2
  else if ( flag1 != null || flag2 != null) {
    if( flag1 != null)
      ret = flag1
    else
      ret = flag2
  } else ret = null

  ret
}

def concat_str_flags = udf((profit_flag_str: String, cmd_str:          String, open_followed_str: String, close_followed_str: String, close_or_open_flag_str: String) => {
  //val retArr: Array[String] = Array(str_flags:_*)
  val retArr: Array[String] = Array(profit_flag_str, cmd_str, open_followed_str, close_followed_str, close_or_open_flag_str)

  val ret = retArr.reduce(merge_flags)

  ret

})

def add_target_2_flags(flag: String, prefix: String): String = {
  if( flag != null)
    prefix + "_" + flag
  else
    prefix
}

def add_target_agg_2_flags(flag: String, prefix: String,    suffix: String): String = {
  if( flag != null)
    prefix + "_" + flag + "_" + suffix
  else
    prefix + "_" + suffix
}

def add_order_2_flags = udf((flag: String) => {
  add_target_2_flags(flag, "order")
})

def add_point_2_flags = udf((flag: String) => {
  add_target_2_flags(flag, "point")
})

def add_point_max_2_flags = udf((flag: String) => {
  add_target_agg_2_flags(flag, "point", "max")
})
val ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("TestCubePivot").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
import ss.implicits._
val sqlContext = ss.sqlContext

val flagsStrDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(List(
  FlagsStr("3_223", "profit", "long", "os", "cs", "close", 5),
  FlagsStr("4_423", null, "long", "os", "cs", "close", 10),
  FlagsStr("5_523", "profit", null, "os", "cs", "close", 15)
))

val h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot_in_memory=flagsStrDataFrame      .cube($"groupby_keys", $"profit_flag_str", $"cmd_str", $"open_followed_str", $"close_followed_str", $"close_or_open_flag_str")      .agg(
  count($"*").as("count_1"),

  sum($"point").as("sum_point"),
  max($"point").as("max_point")
)      .filter($"groupby_keys".isNotNull)      .withColumn("flags",concat_str_flags($"profit_flag_str", $"cmd_str", $"open_followed_str", $"close_followed_str", $"close_or_open_flag_str"))
h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot_in_memory.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot_in_memory")
val h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot = sqlContext.read.table("h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot_in_memory")


//h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot.checkpoint
h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
ss.sparkContext.broadcast(h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot)


val h_mt4trades_stat_cube_order = h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot.withColumn("flags_order", add_order_2_flags($"flags"))       .groupBy($"groupby_keys")      .pivot("flags_order")      .max("count_1")
//h_mt4trades_stat_cube_order.checkpoint

val h_mt4trades_stat_cube_point = h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot.withColumn("flags_point", add_point_2_flags($"flags"))      .groupBy($"groupby_keys")      .pivot("flags_point")      .max("sum_point")
//h_mt4trades_stat_cube_point.checkpoint

val h_mt4trades_stat_cube_point_max = h_mt4trades_with_target_agg_4_pivot.withColumn("flags_point_max", add_point_max_2_flags($"flags"))      .groupBy($"groupby_keys")      .pivot("flags_point_max")      .max("max_point")

val test = h_mt4trades_stat_cube_order.join(h_mt4trades_stat_cube_point, "groupby_keys").join(h_mt4trades_stat_cube_point_max, "groupby_keys")
```

[image]

Comment: _My code is a little mess_ - then you should consider reducing it to a [mcve]. Also, please don't post except [images of exception](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Finally works just fine in the current build so it doesn't look like it is still reproducible.